# tabelas de controle de indice multiplo

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, tabela-banco-de-dados, projeto-de-software

Preciso montar uma tabela de controle de outras tantas tabelas, é basicamente um  controle de índice múltiplo que informa a posição dessas tabelas de dados.

Edição:
depois de varias tentativas até com uso de SQL diretamente acho que cheguei em uma conclusão básica
usando uma unica tabela deixa dificil a montagem e administração apesar da leitura ser relativamente mais facil

a tabela ficou assim por enquanto, ainda não sei se é a melhor configuração
[image: tabela controle]
não tem um numero fixo de tabelas vai de acordo com a ramificação

estou escrevendo primeiramente as macros de leitura dos setores já existentes
um teste para le os bd abertos

```
    Sub BD_Lista()

     Dim loo() As Variant, ss() As Variant, c As Long, cc As Long, l As Long
     cc = 1
     ReDim ss(1 To 5, 1 To cc)
     For Each objwb In Workbooks
          For Each objws In objwb.Worksheets
               loo = objws.Range(bdctrl).Value2
               If loo(1, 1) = Tem_Setor Then
                    c = c + 1
                    If c > cc Then cc = cc + 1: ReDim Preserve ss(1 To 5, 1 To cc):
                    ss(1, c) = objws.Name
                    ss(4, c) = objwb.Path & "\"
                    ss(5, c) = objwb.Name
                    For l = 2 To 3
                         ss(l, c) = loo(l, 1)
                    Next
               End If
          Next objws
     Next objwb
     l = Sheets(wconfig).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
     If l < 4 Then l = 4
     Sheets(wconfig).Range("b4:G" & l).ClearContents
     Sheets(wconfig).Range("b4:F" & 3 + c).Value2 = Array_TransposTo(ss)
End Sub
```

agora re-ataptar o antigo que monta os setores
claro que para esse tipo de situação o ideal seria OOP, mas minha capacidade é pouca para isso

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. A sua pergunta não está redundante. Ela está mesmo é confusa. O que é "algum tipo arcaico apesar de funcional"? Tipo de que? Quando você diz "tabela", está se referindo especificamente a que? Seria uma planilha ou um arquivo CSV? Essa string que você monta, separada por `;`, os dados virão de onde? O que isso representa? Enfim, não dá pra entender praticamente nada do seu problema, e assim fica difícil ajudar. Edite a questão e melhore-a, ok? Se possível, leia antes [ask].

Comment: Sem problemas. Para isso, leia a [help]. O botão "[edit]" fica ali embaixo da pergunta, logo após as tags, entre as opções "compartilhar" e "fechar".

Comment: está difícil definir um modo de expor a duvida , acho que o certo seria apagar o post e tentar me virar aqui

Comment: rs O problema é que ainda tá difícil de entender o que é um "um controle de índice múltiplo". Ao invés de ficar descrevendo como você é "enrolado mesmo" ou como você "até se vira bem com macros", vai direto ao ponto. Explica o que é o tal controle de índice múltiplo, forneça cenários de exemplo (se vc tem uma tabela que "controla" outra, coloque dois exemplos e explique como esse controle se dá), explique o que são as colunas relevantes! Enfim, se você não explicar direito ninguém vai se interessar em ajudar porque vai só gastar tempo tentando adivinhar a sua dificuldade.

Comment: editei, mas sei que ainda não está claro,  vou tentar montar um exemplo grafico para expor a ideia, na cabeça até funciona , mas não sei na pratica

Comment: Ainda não está claro. Talvez o seu problema também seja amplo demais (tem muita informação). Que tal resolver por partes? (aliás, vc pode abrir mais de uma pergunta, não precisa resolver tudo aqui) Por exemplo: quando você diz "índice dos dados", o que isso quer dizer? Seria o endereço da célula onde a tal tabela começa?

Comment: indice seria o indicador do formato da tabela, esse indicador pode apontar para um grupo de outros indices  ou para uma range da planilha , 
não sei como subdividir o problema em varias perguntas ,  mas navegando encontrei possiveis ajustes que vou precisar fazer, como uso de tabelas primarias e segundarias

Comment: Como assim "formato da tabela"? Eu perguntei e você disse que era uma planilha. Não enxergo como ela vai ter "formatos" diferentes. Quais seriam esses formatos? Veja só como cada resposta sua cria duas perguntas (a que já existe, ainda não respondida, e uma nova). Realmente tá bem difícil te ajudar. Acho que você precisa se esforçar um pouco para tornar a sua dificuldade mais pontual e objetiva. Depois volte aqui e edite novamente ou poste uma nova questão. Boa sorte!

Comment: tem como postar uma planilha aqui?, posso montar uma de exemplo e funcional com essa tabela que coloquei como exemplo, mas o fato que preciso de uma estrutura mais elaborada